# How to execute a scp command inside an ssh session?

Tags: bash, sh

How to copy a file located locally in my folder, while being connected in SSH?

This command works perfectly, but only when I run it locally:

```
scp /home/josh/Desktop/DATA/import/file001.csv root@10.0.3.14:/var/www/html/project
```

I would like to have the same result in launching it by being connected in ssh, is it possible?

Comment: When connected via ssh in the remote host try `scp /var/www/html/project/file001.csv josh@your_pc_ip_address:~/Desktop/DATA/import` assuming that csv is located in the source folder and your pc is  properly configured.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: The `scp` command works the same way, but now there is a different local computer. You have to adjust your paths and make sure you can connect to the new remote computer.

Answer (score 5):

You can setup ControlMaster in your `.ssh/config`

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r
```

Then use ssh command mode which will reuse existing connection:

Solution with push ssh session into background:

```
local$ ssh remote
remote$ ~^Z                   # Shift+`, Ctrl+z   - Push ssh into background
local$ scp file remote:/remotepath
local$ fg
remote$
```

You can also to open tunnel via:

```
remote$ ~C                     # Shift+`, Shift+c  - Enter command mode
ssh> -R15000:localhost:22      # tunnel to local:22 from remote:15000
 Forwarding port.
remote$ scp -P15000 localhost:/filepath ~/
remote$ ~C
ssh> -KR15000
 Canceled forwarding.
remote$
```

Comment: What is `~C` on the second line?

Comment: Nevermind, it's the exact sequence of characters `~` and `C` (mind the uppercase) pressed without anything else on the shell prompt. I didn't succeed getting the `ssh>` prompt on the first try but it worked fine on the subsequent attempts.

Comment: It is sequence of keys to press to enter command mode: `Shift+\``, `Shift+c`

Comment: Maybe it's my `ssh(d)` but the `ssh>` prompt doesn't accept any `!` command (it says "Invalid command"). The `help` command lists `-L`, `-R`, `-D`, `-KL`, `-KR`, `-KD` (with arguments) as the only commands it understands.

Comment: I get a remote shell, indeed, and I can run commands on the remote computer. I cannot access the local computer (or I don't know how to do it). It seems to me that the OP asks how to copy a file from the local computer to the remote computer while they are logged into the remote computer through SSH.

Comment: @axiac, I add two another options - tunnel and background

Comment: thank you for your answer ! (y)

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1 : Get the ip address**

```
hostname -I
```

**STEP 2 : Call SCP into SSH**

```
 scp josh@my_ip_address:~/Desktop/DATA/import/file001.csv  /var/www/html/project
```

*ie*: "**josh**" is my name for the connection into my PC

Comment: it will works only if you have sshd localside